# Get screenshoot image bounds on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, screenshot

I'm trying to get image thumbnail when you screen shoot on macOS.
So I'm check all open windows on the system and if Screen capture is open I know the thumbnail is on the screen.
The problem is that I'm trying to "retake" the image of the thumbnail and if the user use Command + Shift + 4 to use custom bounds of screen shoot I don't the custom bounds and I screen shoot all screen bounds.

So how is it possible to get the custom bounds of the screen shoot? (Before the image saved on Desktop)

```
@objc func checkStatusBarForRecordingIndicator() -> Bool {
    
    //Get all windows list
    let windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo([.optionOnScreenOnly], kCGNullWindowID) as! [[String: Any]]
    
    //Check each window name, application name and bounds of window
     for window in windowList {
         let boundsDict = window[kCGWindowBounds as String] as! CFDictionary
         let applicationName = window[kCGWindowOwnerName as String] as! String
         //let windowName = window[kCGWindowName as String] as? String
         //check if it's on menubar or not
         if let bounds = CGRect(dictionaryRepresentation: boundsDict), bounds.origin.y == 0 {
             print(applicationName, bounds)
             //Check if screen recording is on menubar
             if applicationName == screenShootAppName && bounds.origin.x == .zero {
                 print("Screen shoot!")
                 // Create an image from the window
                 let imageView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
                 imageView.image = getSSImage(_bounds: bounds)
                 return true
             }
         }
     }
    
    print("No Screen recording")
    return false
}

//Get screen shoot image
    func getSSImage (_bounds:CGRect) -> NSImage {
        let image = CGWindowListCreateImage(_bounds, .optionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID, .bestResolution)
        return NSImage(cgImage: image!, size: NSSize(width: _bounds.width, height: _bounds.height))
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking for menu bar if you want to find the thumbnail window?

Comment: I see other problems: How will you know the screenshot was actually taken, not cancelled? You can get when screenshot app is launched, but how to know when the  screenshot Is taken, and what are the final bounds?

Comment: @soundflix I check the menu bar for screen recording and I know it’s screen shoot when the origin X is equal to zero (Ian screen recording is different) I don’t why but it’s works from my tests I just need to know the origin and bounds of custom screen shots to “remake” the screen shot

Comment: Are you talking about Apple's `Screenshot.app` that comes with macOS or something else?

Comment: @soundflix Screenshot.app that comes with macOS